# haskell piping strings into IO

Tags: haskell, io

Sorry if this is a common question. I have this simple `IO()` function:

```
greeter :: IO()
greeter = do
  putStr "What's your name? "
  name <- getLine
  putStrLn $ "Hi, " ++ name
```

Now I want to call `greeter` and at the same time specify a parameter that will pre-fill the `getLine`, so that I don't actually need to interact. I imagine something like a function

```
IOwithinputs :: [String] -> IO() -> IO()
```

then I'd do

```
IOwithinputs ["Buddy"] greeter
```

which would produce an `IO` action requiring no user input that would look something like:

```
What's your name?
Hi, Buddy
```

I want to do this without modifying the original `IO()` function `greeter`. I also don't want to compile `greeter` and pipe input from the command line. I don't see anything like `IOwithinputs` in Hoogle. (`withArgs` is tantalizingly typed and named, but isn't at all what I want.) Is there an easy way to do this? Or is it impossible for some reason? Is this what Pipes is for?

Comment: I don't think it is possible without changing `greeter`, unfortunately. `getLine` will *always* read from `stdin`, which is what the user types. The easiest way to change it would be to use `hGetLine` instead, which lets you specify which `Handle` you want to get the line from. It might also be possible (I'm very unsure about this) to do some low-level manipulation and set up a redirect yourself using the `GHC.IO.Handle` module, but it is obviously the last thing you want to do.

Comment: I don't know if this is possible (I initially attempted to find a way to write to `stdin`, but it doesn't let you), b ut this is not what the `pipes` library is for.  `pipes` is for writing a program where you separate your data generators from the data processing steps.  You can use it with IO (and it often is), I would recommend the [tutorial](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes-4.0.0/docs/Pipes-Tutorial.html)

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what's reasonable about this whole idea. To me, it sounds just like a horrible hack. If that `IO ()` argument is supposed to deal with data from other Haskell functions, then why does it not accept it as a parameter? `IOwithinputs :: [String] -> ([String] -> IO()) -> IO()`. (Note that then, basically `IOwithinputs ≡ flip ($)`.)

Comment: @leftaround- I was hoping it wouldn't be too horrible of a hack. I'm teaching a class with Haskell and I have students submitting simple IO programs, all supposed to be the same. I want to automate testing so that I don't have to actually interact with them myself.

Comment: @user2744010 it looks like you might be forced to use shell piping in this case, though I hope I am wrong

Answer (score 3):

As others have noted, there's no clean way to "simulate" `IO` if you're already using things like `getLine` and `putStrLn`. You have to modify `greeter`. You could use the `hGetLine` and `hPutStr` versions and mock out `IO` with a fake `Handle`, or you could use the [Purify Code with Free Monads](http://www.haskellforall.com/2012/07/purify-code-using-free-monads.html) method.

It's far more complex, but also more general and usually a good fit for this kind of mocking, especially when it gets more complex.. I'll explain it briefly below, though the details are somewhat sophisticated.

The idea is that you will be creating your own "fake IO" monad which can be "interpreted" in multiple ways. The primary interpretation is just to use regular `IO`. The mocked interpretation replaces `getLine` with some fake lines and echoes everything to `stdout`.

We'll use the `free` package. The first step is to describe your interface with a `Functor`. The basic notion is that each command is a branch of your functor data type and that the functor's "slot" represents the "next action".

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor #-}

import           Control.Monad.Trans.Free

data FakeIOF next = PutStr  String next
                  | GetLine (String -> next)
                    deriving Functor
```

These constructors are almost like the regular `IO` functions from the point of view of someone building a `FakeIOF` if you ignore the next action. If we want to `PutStr` we must provide a `String`. If we want to `GetLine` we provide a function with only gives the next action when given a `String`.

Now we need a little confusing boilerplate. We use the `liftF` function to turn our functor into a `FreeT` monad. Notice that we provide `()` as the next action on `PutStr` and `id` as our `String -> next` function. It turns out that these give us the right "return values" if we think of how our `FakeIO` `Monad` will behave.

```
-- Our FakeIO monad
type FakeIO a = FreeT FakeIOF IO a

fPutStr :: String -> FakeIO ()
fPutStr s = liftF (PutStr s ())

fGetLine :: FakeIO String
fGetLine = liftF (GetLine id)
```

Using these we can build whatever functionality we like and rewrite `greeter` with very minimal changes.

```
fPutStrLn :: String -> FakeIO ()
fPutStrLn s = fPutStr (s ++ "\n")

greeter :: FakeIO ()
greeter = do
  fPutStr "What's your name? "
  name <- fGetLine
  fPutStrLn $ "Hi, " ++ name
```

This might look a little bit magical---we're using `do` notation without defining a `Monad` instance. The trick is that `FreeT f m` is a `Monad` for any `Monad` `m` and `Functor`f`.

This completes our "mocked" `greeter` function. Now we must interpret it somehow as we've implemented almost no functionality so far. To write an interpreter we use the `iterT` function from `Control.Monad.Trans.Free`. It's fully general type is as follows

```
iterT
  :: (Monad m, Functor f) => (f (m a) -> m a) -> FreeT f m a -> m a
```

But when we apply it to our `FakeIO` monad it looks

```
iterT
  :: (FakeIOF (IO a) -> IO a) -> FakeIO a -> IO a
```

which is much nicer. We provide it a function that takes `FakeIOF` functors filled with `IO` actons in the "next action" position (which is how it gets its name) to a plain `IO` action and `iterT` will do the magic of turning `FakeIO` into real `IO`.

For our default interpreter this is really easy.

```
interpretNormally :: FakeIO a -> IO a
interpretNormally = iterT go where
  go (PutStr s next)   = putStr s >> next    -- next   :: IO a
  go (GetLine doNext)  = getLine >>= doNext  -- doNext :: String -> IO a
```

But we can also make a mocked interpreter. We'll use the facilities of `IO` to store some state, in particular a cyclic queue of fake responses.

```
newQ :: [a] -> IO (IORef [a])
newQ = newIORef . cycle

popQ :: IORef [a] -> IO a
popQ ref = atomicModifyIORef ref (\(a:as) -> (as, a))

interpretMocked :: [String] -> FakeIO a -> IO a
interpretMocked greetings fakeIO = do
  queue <- newQ greetings
  iterT (go queue) fakeIO
  where
    go _ (PutStr s next)   = putStr s >> next
    go q (GetLine getNext) = do
      greeting <- popQ q                -- first we pop a fresh greeting
      putStrLn greeting                 -- then we print it
      getNext greeting                  -- finally we pass it to the next IO action
```

and now we can test these functions

```
λ> interpretNormally greeter
What's your name? Joseph
Hi, Joseph.

λ> interpretMocked ["Jabberwocky", "Frumious"] (greeter >> greeter >> greeter)
What's your name? 
Jabberwocky
Hi, Jabberwocky
What's your name? 
Frumious
Hi, Frumious
What's your name? 
Jabberwocky
Hi, Jabberwocky
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it is easy to do as you ask, but you can do next:

```
greeter' :: IO String -> IO()
greeter' ioS = do
  putStr "What's your name? "
  name <- ioS
  putStrLn $ "Hi, " ++ name

greeter :: IO ()
greeter = greeter' getLine

ioWithInputs :: Monad m => [a] -> (m a -> m ()) -> m()
ioWithInputs s ioS = mapM_ (ioS.return) s
```

and test it:

```
> ioWithInputs ["Buddy","Nick"] greeter'
What's your name? Hi, Buddy
What's your name? Hi, Nick
```

and even more funny with emulation answer:

```
> ioWithInputs ["Buddy","Nick"] $ greeter' . (\s -> s >>= putStrLn >> s)
What's your name? Buddy
Hi, Buddy
What's your name? Nick
Hi, Nick
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you are in `IO` you can't change the way you get input.  To answer your question about `pipes`, yes it is possible to abstract away the input by defining a `Consumer`:

```
import Pipes
import qualified Pipes.Prelude as P

greeter :: Consumer String IO ()
greeter = do
    lift $ putStr "What's your name? "
    name <- await
    lift $ putStrLn $ "Hi, " ++ name
```

Then you can either specify to use the command line as input:

```
main = runEffect $ P.stdinLn >-> greeter
```

... or to use a pure set of strings as input:

```
main = runEffect $ each ["Buddy"] >-> greeter
```